# Estimation of the standard deviation with certain accuracy

Tags: statistics, estimation

I'm trying to solve a problem that goes like this:

> I've made measurements of a physical quantity that is normally distributed. I estimate the mean and standard deviation, with some uncertainty. How many measurements do I need to make to determine the standard deviation with an accuracy of 30%, 10% and 3%?

I've searched for formulas I can use in the class materials and the books the teacher recommends but to be honest I'm not even sure of what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you think "accuracy of 30%" means?

Answer (score 0):

From the iid sample $X_1,...,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ define the estimator of $\sigma^2$ as 
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X}_n)^2.
$$
I interpret from your problem that you want $n$ such that
$$
P\left(\Big|\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}_n-\sigma}{\sigma}\Big|\leq \epsilon\right)\geq 1-\alpha
$$
for some precision $\epsilon> 1$ and some "accuracy" $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

It is a known fact that (for gaussian samples)
$$
n\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}^2_n}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{(n-1)}. 
$$

Choose the sample size
$$
n = \dfrac{q_{1-\alpha}}{(1-\epsilon)^2},
$$
where $q_{1-\alpha}$ is such that $P(\chi^2_{(n-1)}\leq q_{1-\alpha})=1-\alpha$. Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
P\left(\Big|\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}_n-\sigma}{\sigma}\Big|\leq \epsilon\right)&\geq P\left(\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}_n}{\sigma}+1\leq \epsilon\right)\\
&=P\left(n\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}_n^2}{\sigma^2}\leq n(\epsilon-1)^2\right)\\
&=P\left(\chi^2_{(n-1)}\leq q_{1-\alpha}\right)\\
&=1-\alpha.
\end{align*}

Comment: There is something wrong with my reasoning. Can you spot it?

Comment: Despite of being wrong, you can use some of the ideas of my answer to developed something better.